# What typically causes "uwsgi-body-read:...Client closed connection" error?

Tags: file-upload, uwsgi

One of our clients is triggering this error when trying to use our site's file upload functionality:

```
[uwsgi-body-read] Error reading 65536 bytes. 
Content-Length: 543426 consumed: 233 left: 543193 
message: Client closed connection
```

Every other user that has tested uploading the same file has not been able to reproduce this issue even with same OS (Windows) and browser (Chrome). I searched but was unable to find an explanation of the "Client closed connection" error, so I am not clear what the usual causes are. Is there a particular category of issue that typically causes these errors in uWSGI?

I found [this github issue](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/363) which seems to suggest that the problem is related to Safari or IE, but the client is using Chrome on Windows, and we have been unable to reproduce with that same setup. We are using version `2.0.18` of uWSGI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get on a call with the client and figured out what the issue was: he was trying to upload a file out of a shared drive. The file when chosen from a shared drive on a windows machine would fail, triggering the `uwsgi-body-read` error on the backend. When the file was dragged to the desktop and chosen from there, the upload succeeded without issue. The issue is potentially related to windows, because I was able to upload from a shared NAS from a Mac. My team has not yet investigated the issue further.